# BeautifulSoup - check if document is empty (shows nothing in browser)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website and occasionally a page gets thrown up that appears completely empty in the browser. I would like to write an exception for this, but I cannot find a way to check with BeautifulSoup if this is true. I know this seems like an easy problem, but I am a beginner.

The structure of the offending HTML page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  ...   
 </head>
 <body class="something" data-theme="something">
  <csn-mobi>
  </csn-mobi>
  <div id="bitracking" style="display:none">
  </div>
  <script>
   ...
  </script>
  <script>
   ...
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

In other words, the `<body>` has a whole bunch of `<script>` tags and when I do something like:

```
BrowserText = soup.body.text
```

then the problem is that all the script inside the `<script>` tags gets included as well.

But I want to check if there is anything outside the `<script>` tags (but within the `<body>` tag), and if there is nothing, raise an exception.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! There are things in the `<body>` tag in this example... do you mean no plain text content?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I want to check if there is any content in the body tag that gets displayed in the browser, in other words discard all the script content and treat that as "empty"

Comment: @Dexmoody something like this ? compare to `True` or `False` > `tag = row.find("td", {"class" : True})`